# Get null value with Jaxb Unmarshall

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to map a xml file into the Java Object using Jaxb library. I have a schema to validate the xml.

Schema : http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd

I'm using eclipse to generate Pojo from schema above.

OAIPMHtype.java

```
public class OAIPMHtype {

    @XmlElement(name = "ListRecords")
    protected ListRecordsType listRecords;
}
```

ListRecordsType.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ListRecordsType", propOrder = {
    "record",
    "resumptionToken"
})
public class ListRecordsType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<RecordType> record;
}
```

RecordType.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "recordType", propOrder = {
    "header",
    "metadata",
    "about"
})
public class RecordType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected HeaderType header;
    protected MetadataType metadata;
    protected List<AboutType> about;
}
```

MetadataType.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "metadataType", propOrder = {
    "dc"
})
public class MetadataType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected OaiDcType dc;

}
```

OaiDcType.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "oai_dcType", namespace = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/", propOrder = {
    "titleOrCreatorOrSubject"
})
public class OaiDcType {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "identifier", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "subject", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "rights", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "date", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "creator", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "format", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "language", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "source", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "type", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "contributor", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "coverage", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "publisher", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "relation", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "title", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "description", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<ElementType>> titleOrCreatorOrSubject;
}
```

The sample data: data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
    <responseDate>2018-05-14T20:23:15Z</responseDate>
    <request verb="ListRecords" metadataPrefix="oai_dc">http://example.com:7090/api/oai</request>
    <ListRecords>
        <record>
            <header>
                <identifier>oai:example.com:42600</identifier>
                <datestamp>2018-01-22</datestamp>
            </header>
            <metadata>
                <oai_dc:dc
                    xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
                    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
                    <dc:title>Applications of organic and printed electronics :</dc:title>
                    <dc:subject>Electronics</dc:subject>
                    <dc:description>
                    Organic and printed electronics can enable a revolution in the applications of electronics and this book offers readers an overview of the state-of-the-art in this rapidly evolving domain. The potentially low cost, compatibility with flexible substrates and the wealth of devices that characterize organic and printed electronics will make possible applications that go far beyond the well-known displays made with large-area silicon electronics. Since organic electronics are still in their early stage, undergoing transition from lab-scale and prototype activities to production, this book serves as a valuable snapshot of the current landscape of the different devices enabled by this technology, reviewing all applications that are developing and those can be foreseen.
                    </dc:description>
                    <dc:publisher>New York</dc:publisher>
                    <dc:contributor>Cantatore, Eugenio</dc:contributor>
                    <dc:date>2013</dc:date>
                    <dc:identifier>
                    http://example.com/pages/opac/wpid-detailbib-id-42603.html
                    </dc:identifier>
                    <dc:language>eng</dc:language>
                </oai_dc:dc>
            </metadata>
        </record>
    </ListRecords>
</OAI-PMH>
```

Here is code, I'm using to convert Xml to Object:

```
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OAIPMHtype.class);
        File file = new File("data.xml");

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Object dept = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(dept);
```

When I run code above, I have get all other data, except the data of metadata. It return null value the metadata dc of the metadata. I think there are a poblem with sub-schema **oai_dc:dc**. But I don't know how to fix it. Please give me some tips, thanks.

Comment: My guess is that your `JAXBContext` is not complete. Don't create it for single classes, create it for packages with a context path like `package1:package2:...`. Include packages responsible for `oai_dc:dc`.

Comment: Thanks @lexicore. But, It's also not working.

Comment: Consider posting an MCVE project on GitHub. I'll take a look.

Comment: I have used the maven-jaxb2-plugin library and have changed XmlElementRef to XmlElement. Now I have run successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the maven-jaxb2-plugin library and have changed XmlElementRef to XmlElement. It has worked.